# Cursor retrieves a deleted row in table created within plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

Within a plpgsql function I create a table and use a cursor to access its rows. While at first row, I delete a following one and surprisingly (to me at least) the cursor fetches it. When repeating within the same function, it works as I expected it so.

However, if the table pre-exists and is not created within the function, the deleted row is never fetched.

What am I missing?

```
DECLARE
curs1 refcursor;
rec record;

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE test as select generate_series(1,5,1) test_id;

OPEN curs1 FOR SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test_id; 
  LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    RAISE NOTICE 'ROW:%',rec.test_id;
    IF rec.test_id=1 THEN
      DELETE FROM TEST WHERE test_id=3;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE curs1;

RAISE NOTICE 'AGAIN';
--just repeating without deleting

OPEN curs1 FOR SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test_id; 
  LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    RAISE NOTICE 'ROW:%',rec.test_id;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE curs1;
```

Output is:

```
NOTICE:  ROW:1
NOTICE:  ROW:2
NOTICE:  ROW:3
NOTICE:  ROW:4
NOTICE:  ROW:5
NOTICE:  AGAIN
NOTICE:  ROW:1
NOTICE:  ROW:2
NOTICE:  ROW:4
NOTICE:  ROW:5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Postgres cursors are "insensitive" by default. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-declare.html)

> The SQL standard says that it is implementation-dependent whether
>   cursors are sensitive to concurrent updates of the underlying data by
>   default. **In PostgreSQL, cursors are insensitive by default, and can be
>   made sensitive by specifying `FOR UPDATE`**. Other products may work differently.

Bold emphasis mine.

So try the same with using the `FOR UPDATE` clause:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   curs1 refcursor;
   rec record;
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT generate_series(1,5) test_id;

   OPEN curs1 FOR SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY test_id FOR UPDATE; 
   DELETE FROM test WHERE test_id = 3;
   LOOP
      FETCH curs1 INTO rec;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      RAISE NOTICE 'ROW:%',rec.test_id;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE curs1;
END
$$
```

And you get:

> ```
> NOTICE:  ROW:1
> NOTICE:  ROW:2
> NOTICE:  ROW:4
> NOTICE:  ROW:5
> ```

Row 3 is not visible any more.